# How to serialize a property of type XMLNode

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlnode

I have a public class with a property like:

```
[serializable]
public class Data
{
Public XmlNode VariableXMLData {get; set;}
}
```

The VariableXMLData node inturn contains an xmlnode. For example, say:

```
VariableXMLData.OuterXML is "
<VariableXMLData>
<Change>Major</Change><Reason>Unknown</Reason>
</VariableXMLData> ".
```

Issue is: When i serialize this class, the output looks like:

```
<Data>
<VariableXMLData>
<VariableXMLData>
<Change>Major</Change><Reason>Unknown</Reason>
</VariableXMLData>
</VariableXMLData>
</Data>
```

How can i avoid multiple tags for the element name over here. I want to have just one node for `<VariableXMLData>`

Comment: wouldn't it be deserialized properly on the other side, and then simply have your xml node inside?

Comment: No, the issue is - it wont always be a deserialized property. It can be anything. Basically the protocol for incoming xml is: It should be wrapped with root node as <VariableXmlData> and the child nodes can be anything and also any in number

Comment: Give Cedric's answer a spin. If not, and depending on your needs, you might be able to simply JSON it. It should handle the XML ok.

Comment: I still have few doubts on Cedric's response. Waiting to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
[serializable]
public class Data
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    Public XmlNode VariableXMLData {get; set;}

    [XmlElement(ElementName="VariableXMLData")]
    Public XmlNode VariableXMLDataParts {
      get{
         //handle the deserialization => returning the nodes you wish to return
         // example only return the roots descendants...
      }
      set{
           // handle your serialization if needed
      }
}
```

Not sure of it, but i think you can put the second method internal or protected, so it won't be displayed to other assemblies

Comment: Thanks Cedric! Just wanted to reiterate your suggestion to make sure i understood correctly. In the get section of "VariableXMLDataParts", do i return the child nodes? considering my example, should it return nodes "<Change>Major</Change><Reason>Unknown</Reason>" ? Since this can be many in numbers, should i use a NodeList or something? Also, I wont be able to deserialize it, as it can be any xmlstring. The only protocol is : the xml string should be enclosed with <VariableXMLData> tag

Comment: yes you can return the child nodes and if you return the ChildNodes, then the return will be an xmlNodeList. As far as the containment will be other xml nodes, you can still get the childNodes whatever names they have. is this correct?

Comment: Hi Cedric, I added [XmlAnyElement] tag to the Public XmlNode VariableXMLData property. That did solve my issue. Now I am not getting the duplicate <VariableXMLData> tag in my serialized string. But,i am trying to figure out if my approach is correct. Can it have some wrong implications? Please let me know your thougts on this.

Comment: to be sure, you only did this: removing the [XmlIgnore] attribute and replaced it with [XmlAnyElement] attribute without adding a second property like _VariableXMLDataParts_ and now you get the innerXml without the outer tag ?